# php extension on windows xp

Tags: php, windows, php-extension

I've installed php on my xp, but failed to add an extension to mysql

Here is what I did in php.ini:

```
[PHP_MYSQL]
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

and there is such a file in `ext/`

but when I look into `phpinfo()`, only to find that mysql extension is still not added.

What have I did wrongly?

Comment: What kind of PHP installation did you use?

Comment: Binary installation for windows.

Comment: php 5.2.3,
though mysql extension is for 5.2.5,
but I think that's fine,
because my memcache extension is for 5.2.8,
but it still works.

Comment: You will find many similar error descriptions and solution in the PHP bugs database here: http://de2.php.net/results.php?q=php_mysql.dll&l=en&p=all

Comment: Why don't you try XAMPP its everything pre-compiled and composed for ready-to-use in windows: http://www.apachefriends.org/de/xampp-windows.html

Comment: Thanks,downloading now,hope after overwriting things will return to normal.

Answer (score 1):

In your php.ini file do the following:

```
extension=ext/php_mysql.dll
```

This should exist under the `[PHP]` configuration section, not `[PHP_MYSQL]`.

Comment: I've tried put that in [PHP] section first,

but not working,so put it to [PHP_MYSQL] section,

still in vain.

I've installed another extension memcache,without ext/,so I think it'll not help.

Answer (score 1):

> [PHP_MYSQL]

wouldn't this bit cause problems?
guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Apache?  If so, check php.ini in apache\bin as this may be the ini file is use.

As Evgeniy Savichev pointed out, the name of the file being parsed is displayed in phpinfo under 'Loaded Configuration File'

Comment: You can use phpinfo() to see what ini file was parsed in fact.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the mysql client DLLs installed and somewhere on %PATH%. Also, you can use a tool like [depwalker](http://dependencywalker.com) to load the php_mysql.dll and see what the missing dynamic linkage is.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the configuration problems, I would install XAMPP (http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) which installs php, apache and mysql and configures it all as a working server installation.